# Why doesn't hydrolysis of isocyanides take place in basic medium?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

Acidic hydrolysis of alkyl isocyanide gives rise to primary amines and formic acid. But alkyl isocyanides do not undergo hydrolysis in basic medium. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason for the inability of alkyl isocyanides to undergo hydrolysis in basic medium is because the negative charge at the carbon atom $(\ce{R-\overset{+}{N}#\overset{-}{C}\!:})$ repels the nucleophile $\ce{OH-}$ due to both being negatively charged. See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83045/hoffmans-isocyanide-test-how-does-addition-of-concentrated-hcl-degrade-the-iso/83215#83215) for more information.