Carbyl amine test of NH3
Can NH3 give Carbyl amine test?
An -NH2 group can, so I think it should give carbyl amine test. I could not find any resources confirming it. Only R-Nh2 is written in my textbook. Does R include H?

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/83045

Looking at the mechanism of the carbyl amine reaction (example with aniline, borrowed
from Wikipedia here). It is clear that the active intermediate is dichlorocarbene and this will certainly react with ammonia. What it produces is not an isocyanide but cyanide anion (see this Sciencemadness discussion here ). Whether this constitutes a positive test result or not, I leave to your judgement.


The strongly basic conditions under which the chlorocarbene forms would leave cyanide in its ionic, nonvolatile and thus non-smelly form. Which might be a good thing.
